# No "Open" Button after install on Google Play Store, app not in application list

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded my app over to Google Play, and I have found that after a user installs the app, only the uninstall button appears, so they cannot open it. The app cannot be found on home screen/application list, but they can see it in settings < applications. There are similar questions and I have tried all the solutions, including removing "android:enabled" and fixing my intent filter (I am a beginner and honestly I might be doing it wrong... )
Here is my manifest, can I have some help to check it out and see what the problem might be?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SomethingFailedActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SomethingCompleteActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SomethingInfoActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings2"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Main2Activity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ThingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Something2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".SomethingActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Main2Activity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PermissionActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="something-redirect"
                android:scheme="me" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="String"
        android:value="String" />
</application>
```

I have been learning how to code for quite some time and never felt the need to make an account here to ask my questions... I really have no clue here. I even contacted Google Developer help, and they redirected me over to the "Android Developers" site and referenced one StackOverflow link of the similar question that did not work for me.

Comment: Can you try to add a theme to your permission activity and also why do you have  <meta-data
        android:name="String"
        android:value="String" />?

Comment: @DemoDemo I'm not sure how to add a theme to the permission activity, and what would it do? I believe if I do not specify its theme, it will just inherit the application theme, which I declared. Also, there are actual values there that are correct, I just wanted to hide them (?) Thanks for helping out by the way.